# Laravel and Dropbox WebAuth: "Missing CSRF token in session"

Tags: php, dropbox, laravel-5

I'm using Laravel 5.0 and trying to Authorize with Dropbox. I'm loosely following this example: http://dropbox.github.io/dropbox-sdk-php/api-docs/v1.1.x/class-Dropbox.WebAuth.html

When I go to /start. I get redirected to Dropbox and click "Allow", but when I get redirected back to /finish, I keep getting Missing CSRF token in session. Does anyone have any ideas? I have read that `$_SESSION` doesn't work in Laravel but I'm not sure how else to go about it.

Here is the code I am working with:

```
public function start()
{   
    $authorizeUrl = $this->getWebAuth()->start();

    return redirect()->away($authorizeUrl);
}

public function finish()
{       
    $test = $this->getWebAuth()->finish($_GET);

    dd($test);
}

private function getWebAuth()
{   
    $appKey = 'key';
    $appSecret = 'secret';
    $appName = 'name';
    $appRedirect = 'http://example.com/finish';

    $appInfo = new Dropbox\AppInfo($appKey, $appSecret);
    $csrfTokenStore = new Dropbox\ArrayEntryStore($_SESSION, 'dropbox-auth-csrf-token');
    $webAuth = new Dropbox\WebAuth($appInfo, $appName, $appRedirect, $csrfTokenStore);

    return $webAuth;
}
```

**Update 1:**

Okay so I tried getting it working with [Laravel Socialite](http://laravel.com/docs/5.0/authentication#social-authentication) and the [Dropbox Socialite provider](http://socialiteproviders.github.io/providers/dropbox/). I changed my code to what is below, but I get an error when I hit /start. `Driver [dropbox] not supported`. I got really confused on [step 3](http://socialiteproviders.github.io/providers/dropbox/#add-the-event-and-listeners) of the instructions, so maybe I did something wrong there.

*composer.json*

```
"require": {
    "laravel/framework": "5.0.*",
    "dropbox/dropbox-sdk": "1.1.*",
    "laravel/socialite": "~2.0",
    "socialiteproviders/dropbox": "~1.0"
},
```

*Controller*

```
use Socialite;

class ExampleController extends Controller {

    public function start()
    {   
        return Socialite::with('dropbox')->redirect();
    }

    public function finish()
    {       
        $user = Socialite::with('dropbox')->user();

        dd($user->token);
    }
}
```

*config/app.php*

```
'providers' => [
    //'Laravel\Socialite\SocialiteServiceProvider',
    'SocialiteProviders\Manager\ServiceProvider',
],

'aliases' => [
    'Socialite' => 'Laravel\Socialite\Facades\Socialite',
],
```

*app/Providers/EventServiceProvider.php*

```
protected $listen = [
    'SocialiteProviders\Manager\SocialiteWasCalled' => [],
];
```

**Update 2:**

I figured it out, I added this and it worked.

*app/Providers/EventServiceProvider.php*

```
protected $listen = [
    'SocialiteProviders\Manager\SocialiteWasCalled' => [
        'SocialiteProviders\Dropbox\DropboxExtendSocialite@handle',
    ],
];
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Why reinvent the wheel, if you have a wrapper that can do this for you:

https://github.com/GrahamCampbell/Laravel-Dropbox

The reason is that the POST routes are protected with `CSRF`. If you do not want to use a wrapper, you need to disable this security layer, but nobody would recommend that.

Even better is using [Laravel Socialite](http://laravel.com/docs/5.0/authentication#social-authentication). Only the fact is here that Dropbox is not natively supported in it, but [this package](https://packagist.org/packages/socialiteproviders/dropbox) will solve that.

Credits to [ceejayoz](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1902010/ceejayoz) for helping with this!

Comment: That's for Laravel 4. In Laravel 5, making a custom adapter for Socialite is probably a better bet.

Comment: Thanks. https://packagist.org/packages/socialiteproviders/dropbox is a provider for Socialite that may be a better bet in 5.

Comment: That can also be a good solution. My point being in general is that there are already some good providers for this, and that there is no need to override the CSRF token security.

Comment: And now that I've read some more about socialite, I would 100% recommend that. Your link is better, so I'll update it in the post (with credits to you).

Comment: You're right, and as such I've given an upvote. There are situations (like when building APIs) that bypassing the CSRF protection is necessary, so I'll leave my answer too.

Comment: @Blaatpraat I tried getting it to work, but I am still having some issues. I have updated my question with the new code I am working with. Any ideas would be much appreciated.

Comment: @ceejayoz Any ideas ceejay?

Answer (score 1):

**Note:** Using a Dropbox package as in @Blaatpraat's answer is generally a better idea than this. If you're dead-set on using your own logic, though:

Laravel 5 `POST` routes (Dropbox is posting back to you at the end of the process) are protected by default by [the CSRF protection middleware](http://laravel.com/docs/5.0/routing#csrf-protection). Because Dropbox doesn't know your Laravel app's CSRF token (nor does it know to send one), the `_token` parameter is missing and fails the middleware.

You'll need to modify `app/Http/Middleware/VerifyCsrfToken.php` to exempt this route. Where it says:

```
return parent::handle($request, $next);
```

You'll want something like this to bypass the CSRF check on certain routes:

```
if(\Request::is('finish') { return $next($request); }
return parent::handle($request, $next);
```

Comment: I don't think this is right. The redirect at the end of the auth flow is a GET, not a POST. The error message is from the Dropbox SDK, which tries to check that the `state` parameter in the OAuth redirect matches a generate CSRF token (which was stuffed into `$_SESSION`). If `$_SESSION` isn't reliably preserving the CSRF token, the Dropbox SDK will be unable to verify that the `state` parameter is correct. I think the right answer is to use a session dictionary that actually works with Laravel.